# How to remove fractioned Items and add sales to another row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So basically my POS reports don't add up split bills.

If you look at `df.Item` there are items with fractions (1/2, 1/3, etc). I want to drop those lines but add the sales to the proper row.

```
                 Item  Outlet1  Outlet2  Outlet3  Outlet4
2             AIR GIN    162.0      NaN    189.0     54.0
3         AIR GIN 1/3      NaN      NaN      NaN      9.0
4           AIR VODKA    468.0      NaN    585.0    144.0
5       AIR VODKA 1/2      NaN      NaN     18.0      NaN
```

Example output:

```
                 Item  Outlet1  Outlet2  Outlet3  Outlet4
2             AIR GIN    162.0      NaN    189.0     63.0
3           AIR VODKA    468.0      NaN    603.0    144.0
```

I'm not sure where to start, New to python.

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself and [edit] it in. It also wouldn't hurt to remove the columns that aren't relevant for the sake of example, like the categories. Check out [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: It would probably be easier for you to pre-process your input data before you shove it into pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the data doesn't contain any duplicate items. It looks like it's total sales over a certain period, but just the itemization is messed up.

In that case, you can simply remove the fractions with [`.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), then [group](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html).

```
df['Item'] = df['Item'].str.replace(r'\s+\d+/\d+$', '', regex=True)

df.groupby('Item').sum(min_count=1)  # `min_count` to respect NaNs
```

```
           Outlet1  Outlet2  Outlet3  Outlet4
Item                                         
AIR GIN      162.0      NaN    189.0     63.0
AIR VODKA    468.0      NaN    603.0    144.0
```

Then you can `.reset_index()` if you want.

---

P.S. Before your edit, you also had two other columns that weren't really relevant to the problem, but change the process. You could just include them in the groupby:

```
df.groupby(['Category', 'SubCategory', 'Item'])
```